# Xubuntu turning down volume by itself

Tags: sound, xubuntu

I have Xubuntu 14.04 and the sound is turning itself down automatic when I put it on more than 100% or near 100%. It goes back to 50%. What can I do solve this? I tried to clear PulseAudio config files but it didn't help.

Comment: Interesting. What high level application is driving sound? Eg movie player, music player, youtube, etc.

Comment: Are you turning the volume up and down using a hardware switch/dial or purely using the mouse to drag ?  I have a Microsoft Sidewinder X6 keyboard, and its volume dial is very 'bouncy' when it reaches 100% or 0%, it will typically jump 20% away from 100% or 0%

Comment: Using hardware, using mouse, using the terminal, all the ways I put the volume at 100% ou more, it turns back to 50%. Even using alsamixer.